# Нужна расшифровка файла , который зашифрован aes

Tags: java, aes

шифрую файл так

```
static void Chifrovka(String Output) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(Output);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(Output);
          SecretKeySpec sk = new SecretKeySpec("22223456789012345678901234567812".getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sk);

        CipherInputStream cin = new CipherInputStream(in, cipher);
        int ch;

        while ((ch = cin.read()) >= 0)
            {
                out.write(ch);
            }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
```

пробовал такую расшифровку, но ничего не сработало

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(Output);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(Output);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
         SecretKeySpec sk = new SecretKeySpec("22223456789012345678901234567812".getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sk);

        CipherInputStream cin = new CipherInputStream(in, cipher);
        int ch;

        while ((ch = cin.read()) >= 0)
            {
                out.write(ch);
            }
        in.close();
        out.close();
```

Comment: А где выполняются оба куска кода? В одном и том же окружении? Попробуйте вместо просто "AES" указать полностью "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"

Comment: 'java.security.InvalidKeyException: Wrong algorithm: AES or Rijndael required
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCrypt.init(AESCrypt.java:83)
 at com.sun.crrovider.ElectronicCodeBook.init(ElectronicCodeBook.java:94)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.init(CipherCore.java:591)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.init(CipherCore.java:467).......
 
 ' выдает такую ошибку теперь, если где секретный ключь поставить просто aes, то все нормально работает, но он шифрует как-будто там 1 пробел в .txt файле, хотя я писал туда симолов на 2 строки, и дешифрует, какбудто там ничего небыло, пустоту

Comment: они разбиты по методам, и я их использую в мейне, через if else, они не работают сразу вдвоем

Comment: вся проблемма была в том, что файл который был hh.txt повторялся, я получается этот файл вносил, изменял, и такой же выходил на выходе у меня, и в итоге баг

Comment: но осталась проблемма с расшифровкой, он не расшифровывает нифига

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вы уже и написали, проблема была в том, что вы читаете и пишите в файл одновременно. Я бы сделал так:

```
static void Chifrovka(String name, int opmode) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(name);
    // записывать сначала будем в память
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    SecretKeySpec sk = new SecretKeySpec("22223456789012345678901234567812".getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(opmode, sk);

    CipherInputStream cin = new CipherInputStream(in, cipher);
    int ch;

    while ((ch = cin.read()) >= 0)
    {
        byteOut.write(ch);
    }
    in.close();

    // а теперь с памяти пишем на диск
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(name);
    out.write(byteOut.toByteArray());
    out.close();
}
```

И потом:

```
Chifrovka("hh.txt", Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
Chifrovka("hh.txt", Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE);
```

Comment: оу, от души прям, спасибо большое тебе)) спас прям меня